# Live preview for HTML5 Canvas background and color

Tags: javascript, canvas, colors, font-size, font-family

How do I change the background and text color with live preview for HTML5 canvas?

The code I have given on [JSFiddle][1] changes the background and text color only after the color palette is closed. I also want a variable font-family and font-size for the text on canvas. I could not find a solution anywhere.

If the code cannot be run, please solve the problem by creating an html file.

Please have a look at this [image][2] for more information.

Any suggestions and help would be appreciated.

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/p0z1vau3/
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpETT.png
[3]: Source: https://codepen.io/stefan0uh/pen/QzJVxa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code change the eventListener to:

```
color.addEventListener("input", render);
bgcolor.addEventListener("input", render);
```

You can read more info about color picker here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color

Comment: I very much appreciate your help. Now the issue is resolved. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

if you need how to code the change of font size and font family use the below code. it also include answer to both questions. replace your javascript code with this.

```
    const color = document.getElementById("color");
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const style = document.getElementById("font-family");
  const size = document.getElementById("font-size");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // onload
    window.onload = () => {
    render();
};

    // Eventlistner
    color.addEventListener("input", render);
    bgcolor.addEventListener("input", render);
  style.addEventListener("change", render);
  size.addEventListener("change", render);

    // text positions
    function render() {
    drawBackground();
    drawText("top", canvas.height - 48,size.value,style.value);
    drawText("bottom", canvas.height - 18);
 
}
    // Need live preview for background color
    function drawBackground() {
    ctx.fillStyle = bgcolor.value;
    ctx.fillRect(0, canvas.height - 80, canvas.width + 10, 150);
    ctx.restore();
}
    
    function drawText(text, position, fontSize, fontStyle) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    ctx.font = fontSize+"px "+ fontStyle; // Need variable font-family & size

    // Need live preview for color
    var top = [{ 
    text: `      Text`, font: `lighter ${ctx.font}`, fillStyle: color.value}];

    var bottom = [{
    text: `......Text`,
    font: `lighter ${ctx.font}`,
    fillStyle: color.value }];

    fillMixedText(ctx, text === "top" ? top : bottom, 20, position);//text positioning
}
    // fillStyle
    function fillMixedText(ctx, args, x, y) {
    let defaultFillStyle = ctx.fillStyle;
    let defaultFont = ctx.font;

    args.forEach(({ text, fillStyle, font }) => {
    ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle || defaultFillStyle;
    ctx.font = font || defaultFont;

    ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
    x += ctx.measureText(text).width;
    });
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: Now the whole issue is resolved. Thank you so much with appreciation.